# How to parse and format time based on a specific timezone with Dayjs?

Tags: javascript, timezone, dayjs

I am in Paris (`Europe/Paris` timezone). When parsing `00:00`, I get the time object in my local timezone → OK.

Still in Paris, I would like to parse `00:00` as if it was in the `America/Los_Angeles` timezone, to get an object that corresponds to 9:00 in Paris. In other words, something like

```
theMagicalFunction("00:00", "Europe/Paris")  // outputs 2023-09-22T00:00:00.00+02:00
theMagicalFunction("00:00", "America/Los_Angeles")  // outputs 2023-09-22T00:00:00.00-08:00
```

When I wanted to try this with Dayjs:

```
// loading the hour 0 in the Europe/Paris timezone, and then converting it to the Europe/Paris timezone (yes, it is the same, for symmetry with the next one)
dayjs.tz({ hour: "00" }, 'Europe/Paris').tz('Europe/Paris').toISOString()
// output is 2023-09-21T22:00:00.000Z → OK

// loading the hour 0 in the America/Los_Angeles timezone, and then converting it to the Europe/Paris timezone
dayjs.tz({ hour: "00" }, 'America/Los_Angeles').tz('Europe/Paris').toISOString()
// output is 2023-09-21T22:00:00.000Z → BAD, I expected a string localized to America/Los_Angeles
```